# Colored text background with rounded corners

Tags: swift, text, background, cornerradius

I'm currently working on an iOS application in Swift, and I need to achieve the text effect shown in the attached picture.

I have a label which displays some text wrote by the user, and I need to make the text background corners (not the label background) rounded.

Is there a way to do that?
I'd search the web and Stackoverflow but with no luck.

Thank you.

[image: What I need to achieve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that could help you. The result I got is quite similar to what you want.

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {

    let textViewPadding: CGFloat = 7.0

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: NSMakeRange(0, self.text.count)) { (rect, usedRect, textContainer, glyphRange, Bool) in

            let rect = CGRect(x: usedRect.origin.x, y: usedRect.origin.y + self.textViewPadding, width: usedRect.size.width, height: usedRect.size.height*1.2)
            let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 3)
            UIColor.red.setFill()
            rectanglePath.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll try it ASAP and let you know :)

Comment: You can try but I'm not sure

Comment: Perfect! I've managed to make it work at every key is pressed by the user! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[Xavier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49073244/20183011) solution works great.
If you want update background in real-time, use: textView.setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).